# "cannot do signed 4 byte relocation" on compile

Tags: compiler-construction, ghc, haskell

I'm going through [Real world Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/functional-programming.html), and got to the example:

```
-- file: ch04/InteractWith.hs
-- Save this in a source file, e.g. Interact.hs

import System.Environment (getArgs)

interactWith function inputFile outputFile = do
  input <- readFile inputFile
  writeFile outputFile (function input)

main = mainWith myFunction
  where mainWith function = do
          args <- getArgs
          case args of
            [input,output] -> interactWith function input output
            _ -> putStrLn "error: exactly two arguments needed"

        -- replace "id" with the name of our function below
        myFunction = id
```

But when I try to compile it (`ghc --make InteractWith`) I get this error:

```
$ ghc --make InteractWith
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( InteractWith.hs, InteractWith.o )

/var/folders/38/38dlZO7fEXyCgGIFUZA0Ok+++TI/-Tmp-/ghc91310_0/ghc91310_0.s:309:0:
    suffix or operands invalid for `push'

/var/folders/38/38dlZO7fEXyCgGIFUZA0Ok+++TI/-Tmp-/ghc91310_0/ghc91310_0.s:358:0:
    suffix or operands invalid for `push'

/var/folders/38/38dlZO7fEXyCgGIFUZA0Ok+++TI/-Tmp-/ghc91310_0/ghc91310_0.s:384:0:
    32-bit absolute addressing is not supported for x86-64

/var/folders/38/38dlZO7fEXyCgGIFUZA0Ok+++TI/-Tmp-/ghc91310_0/ghc91310_0.s:384:0:
    cannot do signed 4 byte relocation

/var/folders/38/38dlZO7fEXyCgGIFUZA0Ok+++TI/-Tmp-/ghc91310_0/ghc91310_0.s:387:0:
    32-bit absolute addressing is not supported for x86-64

/var/folders/38/38dlZO7fEXyCgGIFUZA0Ok+++TI/-Tmp-/ghc91310_0/ghc91310_0.s:387:0:
    cannot do signed 4 byte relocation
```

I'm using GHC 6.10.4 on Mac OS 10.6 (Snow Leopard).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having similar problems compiling almost anything in Snow Leopard.  The solution I found was to replace the contents of `/usr/bin/ghc` (which is actually just a shell script) with the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

exec /Library/Frameworks/GHC.framework/Versions/610/usr/lib/ghc-6.10.4/ghc -B/Library/Frameworks/GHC.framework/Versions/610/usr/lib/ghc-6.10.4/. -optc-m32 -opta-m32 -optl-m32 -dynload wrapped ${1+"$@"}
```

I think it's actually just adding `-optc-m32 -opta-m32 -optl-m32` but I can't remember...

(I originally found this somewhere on the internets, but I don't remember where.  It did take me a while too.)

Comment: That appears to have fixed my problem. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you update to Snow Leopard recently? I believe this happens when you're trying to use an executable in Snow Leopard that was built using Leopard.